# What can cause section handle leaks?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe, handle, resource-leak

This is a follow-up question to [my previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846115/how-to-trace-handle-leaks)

As suggested in [this answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846115/how-to-trace-handle-leaks/7846289#7846289), I used *ProcessExplorer* to analyze a list of handles that my application is using to find a handle leak.

The handles that are leaking are of type **Section**.

What exactly is a section handle, where is it used and what can cause section handles to leak?

**I'm not using memory mapped files in my code.**

Comment: You you are not using memory mapped files, is somebody else? Which components you're using? Any third party dll's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting Mark Russinovich's Inside Windows 2000 (what is now called Windows Internals),

> The *section object*, which the Win32 subsystem calls a *file mapping object*, represents a block of memory that two or more processes can share.

So, it's a memory mapped file. They'd leak if you created a memory mapped file and failed to close it. Pretty hard to be much more specific.

Comment: Thanks. The bad news is: I'm not using memory mapped files at all :(

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the problem was in a low-level function that counts the number of threads of the current process. This function used the

```
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
```

API function which returns a handle, which was not closed properly. I am not sure why this produces a section handle leak though.

Comment: Right, but it's one rather unexpected explanation for section handle leaks, so it answers at least part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

A memory mapped file not associated with a file handle can be used for IPC (communication between process). If you do not use them directly, perhaps one of your unit or component is doing some IPC communication. It is very likely that you use a component to connect to another process, and do not release it as requested.

First action to be taken is to *track for any memory leak* (using FastMM4 debug mode), and you'll certainly find some un-released objects in your code.

Since handles are commonly allocated by objects, from my experiment, resolving all memory leaks will resolve handle leaks.

If you do not have any memory leak, there is some [`CreateFileMapping()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) calls to check for a corresponding `CloseHandle()` in all your source code (including third-party source).

Answer (score 1):

The section handle leak in .net is due to the Microsoft Hotfix KB2670838.
Uninstall this update and the section handle leak issue (Out of Memory) will be fixed.

```
Parameter is not valid. at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
```